# Expand dimension to Tensor and assign value

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

My tensor shape is 32,4 like

```
input_boxes =  [
                 [1,2,3,4],
                 [2,2,6,4],
                 [[1,5,3,4],[1,3,3,8]],#some row has two 
                 [1,2,3,4],#some has one row
                 [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,3,4]],
                 [1,7,3,4],
                  ......
                 [1,2,3,4]
               ]
```

I like to expand to 32,5 at the first column like tf.expand_dims(input_boxes, 0).
Then assign value to the first column with row number like

```
input_boxes =  [
                 [0,1,2,3,4],
                 [1,2,2,6,4],
                 [[2,1,5,3,4],[2,1,3,3,8]],#some row has two 
                 [3,1,2,3,4],#some has one row
                 [[4,1,2,3,4],[4,1,3,3,4]],
                 [5,1,7,3,4],
                  ......
                 [31,1,2,3,4]
               ]
```

How can I do in Tensorflow?

Comment: I don't understand the shape of `input_boxes`, if it is `(32, 4)`, how can there be some rows with two "sub-rows"? Or is `input_boxes` just a Python list? How are you representing that data in TensorFlow? Also `tf.expand_dims` does not increase the size of an axis, like what (I think) you want, it just adds a new singleton dimension - so, for example, if `input_boxes` has shape `(32, 4)`, `tf.expand_dims(input_boxes, 0)` would have shape `(1, 32, 4)`.

Comment: Yeah that two rows and one row I need to figure out. Say if I want to change from (32,4) to (32,5), how can I change and update row number?

Comment: The simple case with a tensor with shape `(32,4)` is easy, just do `tf.concat([tf.dtypes.cast(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(input_boxes)[0]), 1), input_boxes.dtype), input_boxes], axis=1)`.

Comment: Yours is so efficient. How row index is assigned to the first column?

Comment: `tf.range(tf.shape(input_boxes)[0])` makes a vector from 0 to 31, then `expand_dims` is used to turn it into a `(32, 1)` matrix, then casted to match `input_boxes` type (in case it is not integer, for example), then `concat` along the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section (thanks to `jdehesa`) for the **benefit of the Community**.

For example, we have a Tensor of Shape (7,4) as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_boxes =  tf.constant([[1,2,3,4],
                 [2,2,6,4],
                 [1,5,3,4],
                 [1,2,3,4],
                 [1,2,3,4],
                 [1,7,3,4],
                 [1,2,3,4]])

print(input_boxes)
```

Code to `expand` to `(7,5)` at the `First Column` with the values of `First Columns` being the respective `Row Number` is shown below:

```
input_boxes = tf.concat([tf.dtypes.cast(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(input_boxes)[0]), 1), input_boxes.dtype), input_boxes], axis=1)
print(input_boxes)
```

Output of the above code is shown below:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(7, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 2, 6, 4],
       [2, 1, 5, 3, 4],
       [3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 1, 7, 3, 4],
       [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=int32)>
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!